# compare two images with low quality

Tags: c#, image, opencv, compare, emgucv

I am working on an algorithm to extract diffrences between two images with diffrent qualities for example you have a photoshop file which is created by a designer and then you print it out with some devices and you have scaned it and saved it as a bmp file.
the main question is how we can compare these two images?
it is not possible two compare pixel by pixel, because in scaned version many objects have changed for example lines become thicker.
my idea is to find any shapes in two images then compare them based on location and other shape featurs but the main problem is that in low quality images it become too difficult to compare.because in low quality we have noise and after noise canceling some shapes will be lost. for example when i use open and close or morphology filters i lose some characters such as "i Q O 0" or other shapes.what is your opinion ?

Comment: If **you** are working on this algorithm, you should have some retults already. Show us, what have you done.

Comment: sure i will upload that results.

Answer (score 1):

you have image1 & image2 that have to compare .In both images find corners by hough transform then register two images by corners.you can use [findhomogrphy()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html?highlight=findhomography#Mat%20findHomography%28InputArray%20srcPoints,%20InputArray%20dstPoints,%20int%20method,%20double%20ransacReprojThreshold,%20OutputArray%20mask%29) .Now the two images are the same size.In the finial you can use matchTemplate() for find difference between two images.

Comment: For more details use [this](http://opencv-code.com/tutorials/automatic-perspective-correction-for-quadrilateral-objects/) link.

Comment: thank you so much let me work on it , it seems useful to me. :)

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion of @Mostafa Sataki sounds good. An alternative would be to align the images as suggested, then use a similarity measure such as [MSE or PSNR](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/highgui/video-input-psnr-ssim/video-input-psnr-ssim.html#image-similarity-psnr-and-ssim)

Another possibility would be to try to [match keypoints](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_features2d.html#matching-keypoints) from the two images to see if they are the same image.

Comment: The proper  way to say thank you is to up vote the answer.